# How to procedurally generate command in bash script using string interpolation with spaces?

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line, python, string

I'm trying to create a simple script that uses a list of months like this:

> (Jan Feb)

To generate and execute this command:

> python ExpenseManager.py -p Inputs/Jan\ 2019\ Debit.CSV Inputs/Jan\
>   2019\ Credit.CSV -p Inputs/Feb\ 2019\ Debit.CSV Inputs/Feb\ 2019\
>   Credit.CSV

This is the program I've written to that effect:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
clear
months=(Jan Feb)
args=()
for month in ${months[@]}; do
  args=(${args[@]} -p "Inputs/${month}\\ 2019\\ Debit.CSV" "Inputs/${month}\\ 2019\\ Credit.CSV")
done
python ExpenseManager.py "${args[@]}"
exit 0
```

And this, in theory, is working. When I echo the resulting command, I get the exact command I want:

> python ExpenseManager.py -p Inputs/Jan\ 2019\ Debit.CSV Inputs/Jan\
>   2019\ Credit.CSV -p Inputs/Feb\ 2019\ Debit.CSV Inputs/Feb\ 2019\
>   Credit.CSV

Now when I copy/paste the command created by this program and execute it, it works fine. However when I have Bash execute the command, it includes the backslashes that I use to include the escape backslash in Bash:

> Namespace(filepairs=[['Inputs/Jan\', '2019\', 'Debit.CSV',
>   'Inputs/Jan\', '2019\', 'Credit.CSV'], ['Inputs/Feb\ 2019\
>   Debit.CSV', 'Inputs/Feb\ 2019\ Credit.CSV']]

I've tried several solutions to get this to work:

- I've tried making the args a single string and building off of that
- I've tried surrounding the args with single quotes and using double quotes around spaces like this:

> args=(${args[@]} -p 'Inputs/${month}" "2019" "Debit.CSV
>   "Inputs/${month}" "2019" "Credit.CSV")

- I've tried separating each part of the arg that requires a space using quotes like this:

> ```
>   args=(${args[@]} -p "Inputs/${month}" "2019" "Debit.CSV" "Inputs/${month}\ 2019\ Credit.CSV")
> ```

I've looked at other solutions here and elsewhere but nothing seems to do the trick. So rather than continue to get stuck on this I was hoping someone could tell me the magic trick to have Bash execute this procedurally-built, interpolated command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `echo` to see what command is being executed. It prints the command *after* parsing, that is after quotes and escapes have been applied *and removed*); therefore, if the output of `echo` includes quotes and/or escapes like you'd expect to see in a raw command line (i.e. before parsing), it indicates that something is terribly wrong. Compare the output from these two `echo` commands:

```
$ month=Jan
$ var="Inputs/${month}\\ 2019\\ Debit.CSV"
$ echo $var
Inputs/Jan\ 2019\ Debit.CSV
$ echo Inputs/Jan\ 2019\ Debit.CSV
Inputs/Jan 2019 Debit.CSV
```

In the first, the escapes are printed, indicating that they *weren't* parsed, applied, and removed. In the second, they're gone, indicating that they *were* parsed, applied, and removed.

So, how to fix it? Two rules: 1) don't put quotes or escapes in variables (except in weird cases where the string's going to go through an extra level of parsing), and 2) instead, put double-quotes around all variable references (including `${args[@]}`) (again, there are some weird exceptions). Also, you can add to an array with `array+=("new" "elements")`.

Here's the fixed script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
clear
months=(Jan Feb)
args=()
for month in "${months[@]}"; do
  args+=(-p "Inputs/${month} 2019 Debit.CSV" "Inputs/${month} 2019 Credit.CSV")
done
python ExpenseManager.py "${args[@]}"
exit 0
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much for your help.